# If else statement for Gravity form entries

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

Im using Gravity Forms to create an WooCommerce order programmatically, and Im using an upload file field to set a url of the uploaded file as an order note.

However, I don't want to set the note if the user doesn't upload a file. How can I set a conditional in php for an Gravity form entry?

`$order->add_order_note('<a href='.$filename.'>Uploaded File</a>');`

This outputs the a element regardless of entry. How do I set the conditional on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
if( $filename != '' ){
    $order->add_order_note('<a href='.$filename.'>Uploaded File</a>');
}
```